# Find the Minimum value in a range with out considering "Text"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have a range of data that has both Numerical and "--", i want an formula to return the Minimum value with out considering "--"

[image]

In range A:A the minimum value should be 0

and

In range B:B the minimum value should be 1

and if only "--" the minimum should be "--"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `SMALL` instead of `MIN` that will return an error when there are no numbers in the range, so you can use `IFERROR` to convert to the required value, e.g. in A9 copied across

`=IFERROR(SMALL(A2:A7,1),"--")`

Answer (score 0):

Paste this to `A9`:

`=IF(COUNTIF(A2:A7,"--")=COUNTA(A2:A7),"--",MIN(A2:A7))`

First check if all "--", if not then get `MIN()`.